# Why it thunderbird 78 hanging when talking to IMAP mail server?

Tags: ssl, imap, thunderbird

After automatic update from thunderbird 68 to 78, thunderbird hangs in talking to our organization's email server. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7):

The hint came to our sysadmin from https://help.blacknight.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011553098-Issues-with-Thunderbird-78-.

It turns out that starting with thunderbird 78, mozilla disabled TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. Our mail server is old and not updated.

The link above shows how to use config editor, specifically

1. Go to options
2. Scroll all the way down to Config editor...
3. Accept the risks
4. Search for *security.tls.version.min*
5. Set it to 1.
6. Restart thunderbird.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this solved it! Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you I had no idea how to resolve this!

Comment: A million thanks for this. Problem solved. (Was on the verge of telling folks that Thunderbird was FUBAR and we'd have to migrate to Evolution.)

Antique mailservers must be quite common for restricted use on small intranets. In our case as a mail archive store. It's just a place to move mail messages to, because some people want to store gigabytes of them locally.

Comment: The Config editor is found by choosing menu at top right, the three horizontal bars, then Preferences. Then scroll to bottom for button to select Config editor....  Hard to find it!

Comment: Oh wow... Thunderbird really, really, REALLY should show some kind of error message (at the very least in the Dev-Console) if the connection is refused due to this. Thanks so much, worked for me, too

Comment: In latest thunderbird you need to also set security.tls.version.enable-deprecated to True or else you cannot set security.tls.version.min to 1

Comment: That is version 102.6.0 Dec 2023

Answer (score 0):

A million thanks for this. Problem solved. (Was on the verge of telling folks that Thunderbird was FUBAR and we'd have to migrate to Evolution.)

Antique mailservers must be quite common for restricted use on small intranets. In our case as a mail archive store. It's just a place to move mail messages to, because some people want to store gigabytes of them locally.